# Skver Tallis Katan

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-katan

On certain Judaica websites, such as [here](http://www.judaicasavings.com/product.asp?P_ID=5667) and [here](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/tallits-tallit-kattan---arba-kanfos.html), they have a special tallis katan for sale that they describe as being "Skver" and I assume they mean the Hasidic Dynasty of that name.

The first link, there seems to be nothing special about the tallis katan they are selling as "Skver." It appears to be like any Hasidic tallis katan (wool, "tzeirei holes", etc.) In the second link, when you click on the "Skver" category, it leads you to a mesh tallis katan. That doesn't sound Hasidic!

What is a "Skver" tallis katan? How does it differ from a normal tallis katan? Perhaps it is referring to a special way to tie the tzitzis, perhaps according to some "Skver" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Chasidim wear a V-Neck Talis Kotton. Skver wears a round neck Talis Kotton, however they still have two holes for the Tzitzis like the other Chasidim therefore the regular Askenaz round neck Talis Kotton does not work for them as it only has one hole by the Tzitzis.

Thus Minhag Skver is Round-Neck and 2-Holes.

Comment: Okay, so like a Chabad tallis but with "tzeirei holes" instead of Chabad holes.

Comment: @ezra - Yes....

Comment: I can attest to the correctness of this answer. +1.